# Sharepoint to support MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, model-view-controller

I am a sharepoint developer and an asp.net mvc developer and the thing is I prefer developing Asp.net MVC web applications compare to sharepoint. It hurts but reality bites that sharepoint is totally frustrating for developers or maybe not for some of you but for me most of the time it does although I still love developing sharepoint. When MVC was introduced many developers embraced it and until now many are still craving for it. As to what I can see, if MVC will be fully integrated with sharepoint I could possibly say that sharepoint can make a big difference and say thanks to MVC.

My question is could sharepoint ever have the chances to be integrated with MVC? What part of sharepoint could possibly fail MVC to be integrated? Could you give a big reason why Sharepoint is a big NO to MVC?

Comment: This question could only be answered my Microsoft.

Comment: Sharepoint is so complicated... If they will integrate it with MVC, I doubt it won't be easy. Somehow there is a work-around for this so you can work on MVC while your application reside on the sharepoint server and somehow you can optimize sharepoint Api's. Good thing is you are coding the mvc way.There may be chances that sharepoint can be integrated with microsoft but the next question to that is when? :)

Comment: I think only microsoft can answer that. But I'm pretty sure that everything that is possible, microsoft will try to deliver it. As far as I can see sharepoint and Mvc have the possibilities, but I'm not sure if they will but I am hoping that it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint is a really big, complex web application with a huge install base and no control over end user customization. That sort of system can't be rewritten from scratch without a really good reason, and even when there is a really good reason, any attempt to do so is doomed to failure.

There are ways you can use MVC alongside SharePoint though. Any .net application running on the right server can access the SharePoint API. You can also wrap mvc views in SharePoint web parts / pages. Getting the web forms view engine to run under SharePoint requires the sort of hacking that will never get past corporate infrastructure people, but hosting Razor views in SharePoint is relatively easy to set up.

Comment: MVC is a completely different architecture, so there wouldn't be much unchanged, and your other suggestion just doesn't make sense. The VS2008 integration is nothing special - MVC 1 & 2 use .net 3.5, and there is no attempt to reuse code designed for something entirely different. MVC3 requires .net 4 / VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SharePointMVC project](http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I've read that already and it is just a work around but not totally coding MVC-like of codes say on sharepoint webpart development. It is a work around to host mvc apps in a sharepoint server and utilize the sharepoint api. But obviously MVC is not localized on Sharepoint yet. Also scottGu says "Currently MVC doesn't directly integrate with SharePoint. That is something we'll be looking at supporting in the future though." so the question is will it be possible? Hopefully it will, but when?

Comment: I think sharepoint architecture will not be changed in future. If Microsoft decide to build something like Sharepoint, but MVC based it will be other project. It's just my opinion.